# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, iframe

The content of the iframe element I use in my project is saying refused to connect." The Error i am getting is "refused to display 'https://clideo.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'".I am using React.js with python flask as backend. how can I fix this error?

I have tried using X-Frame-Bypass web component but it still didn't work.

```
<iframe src="https://clideo.com/editor/" width="100%" height="100%" title="Edit Video"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error cannot be fixed, the `X-Frame-Options` header is set by the server you are connecting to (e.g., `https://clideo.com/editor/`) - that server has stated they do not want anyone (other than then) rendering their site in an iframe.

All browsers will respect this header, as it's commonly used for click hijacking (e.g., you render a site in an iframe and put a layer on top of it to intercept clicks/keystrokes).

Comment: Thanks,I know that but I have read somewhere that you can do it by using Server Side to render it. Is there anyway using the server side?

Comment: You'd need to proxy the request through a server you control - then you wouldn't use `https://clideo.com/editor/` as the URL but `https://server-i-control.com/proxy?https://clideo.com/editor/` or similar

Comment: Can you give a code snippet of it?

Comment: No - this is out of scope for the question, and it isn't a small code snippet, it's an entire application, it would also only work if you had a server to use. Attempt this solution yourself, and if you get stuck, post another question.